# Hide columns which its row have zero value using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hide, hidden

I have an Excel worksheet with the values is numbers in columns A,B,C,D and F (these columns have multiple rows). All I want is when click on a button, all columns which its rows have zero value will be hidden.

So if anyone have solution for this, please help me! Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried any code already? If so could you post it on your question. Also is it if on column has a 0 or all the columns are 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideZeros()
  HideCells (1)
End Sub
Sub HideCells(Col_Num As Integer)
Dim Row_num As Integer
For Row_num = 1 To 10
  If Sheet1.Cells(Row_num, Col_Num).Value = 0 Then Sheet1.Cells(Row_num, Col_Num).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next
End Sub
```

The above is to point you in the right direction to modify as you wish. It will delete any cells with the 0 value in the first 10 rows of sheet 1 column A and move the rest up.. 
You can't hide one cell you can only hide a row / column. So delete is your only option...Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have created two solutions dependent on what it is you want to do. In the code i  have explained what each step is doing the rest of the code is just repeated for the different columns. 
The first one hides the column if and row in that column is equal to zero:

```
    Sub HideRowsWhereAnyRowIsZero()

    Dim i As Long 'Declarations

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count 'Find the last row and loop through until reached
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "0" Then 'if the cell equals 0 then move to next step if not move to next cell
                Cells(i, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide column
                    If Cells(i, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Exit For 'if column has been hidden then break the loop
        End If 'if cell doesnt  equal 0 move on
    Next i 'creates loop to go thorugh each row in column


    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "0" Then
            Cells(i, 2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                If Cells(i, 2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = "0" Then
            Cells(i, 3).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                If Cells(i, 3).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" Then
            Cells(i, 4).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                If Cells(i, 4).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "0" Then
            Cells(i, 6).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                If Cells(i, 6).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

The next piece of code hides only where all the rows in the column are 0

```
Sub HideColumnsWhenAllRowsAreZero()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'finds the last row for column A

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then 'sum the values of the column if it equals 0 then move on to hide column

        Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hides column

    End If 'Ends statement for column

Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B1:B" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then

        Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If

Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

       If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C1:C" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then

        Range("C1:C" & Lastrow).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If

Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D1:D" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then

        Range("D1:D" & Lastrow).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If

Lastrow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F1:F" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then

        Range("F1:F" & Lastrow).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If


End Sub
```

I would suggest stepping thorugh the code (using F8) and try to understand what is actually happening.